# Skype video not working after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webcam, skype

I used Skype with this command on Ubuntu 11.10:

`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype`

But since I upgraded to 12.04 it dosn't work and I can't use my video (Webcam).

I have latest libv4l and my Webcam works with other apps.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me.  Skype is supposed to "just work", including video telefonie.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The path to v4l1compat.so has been changed. So, you should use the command:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

Comment: Im having a similar problem trying to get a Trust webcam to work on a Packard Bell with Ubuntu 12.04 with Skype. Where do I install the above command? Sorry Im very new to Lynx

Comment: Is there a way to set Skype to launch this way by default?

Comment: Yes there is. I used this tutorial: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/219 and it worked for ubuntu 11.10. In 12.04 the location of the compat lib changed, so you should the above line instead.

Comment: These seemed at first to work but I am afraid for me it just does not.After a few years of using these hacks I cannot get this one above to work I am afraid. I am using a logitech quick cam 2500 and when skype starts now and I press the test button I get a fleeting picture and then it freezes. When I tested using another connection there is no video at all. I am getting to the stage when this is being a pain and I would like to be able to help create a solution to this.

Comment: For now I will go through all the related webcam/skype older solutions (mine included) and redirect them to the solution above even though it does not work for me.

Comment: I have a similar problem to the one in the above comment. The webcam, a logitech quickcam, works for a few seconds, then either it freezes completely or starts changing the images once every so often.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you should use the path /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so also on *64-bit* systems. Re: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176066/ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded-error-message-but-so-exists/176070#176070

Answer (score 8):

First you will need to make sure you have *libv4l-0* installed.

If you have installed *Ubuntu restricted extras* then you should already have it if not open Software Centre and install *Ubuntu restricted extras* from there.

Once this is done open a Terminal and copy and paste the following command

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

After you have provided your password a text editor will open.
Line 4 should look like this

```
Exec=skype
```

Replace with this text

```
Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'
```

Save and exit the text editor and close the terminal. Now you can open Skype and test your webcam via *'options'* then *'video devices'*