# USB plugin webcam with Skype 2.2 beta

Tags: 12.04, usb, webcam, skype

I have a pretty generic USB webcam (it is a generic sphere shaped webcam i got from IBM, it says IBM on it) that I want to work with skype.  In past installations of ubuntu, I could get this webcam working with skype by using this command (or something very similar to it)

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04, and I just installed Skype for Linux beta 2.2 through the APT software center.  Needless to say when I plug in the web cam and use skype, i cannot get video working.  I already have this web cam **working** with gmail video chat.

When I execute the above line of code to start skype, i get this output:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

And then skype starts up and works like normal, but when I try to test or use the web cam nothing happens, no error but no video.

In the skype options: Video Devices tab, it says that it finds a PC Camera at /dev/video0.  When I click "Test" i still just get a black screen and no light on the web cam.

2 questions:

How do I use Ubuntu to tell the model and driver for the web cam, so I can troubleshoot easier?

Does anyone know off the top of their heads how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This has been answered here 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126765/skype-video-not-working-after-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After installing skype 4 downloaded from skype website, problem solved. 
Before I have followed this how-to: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/219, but I'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.