# How do I get my (UBUNTU certified) Dell N5050's webcam to work with google video chat and Skype using version 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dell, webcam, skype, google-talk

I changed the OS on my Dell N5050 to UBUNTU 12.04 from Windows 7, and nowo cheese is the only thing willing to talk with the laptop's camera.

Is there a download or "sudo apt-get" command set I can use to get my system to interface right?

Answer (score 1):

You may also need a preloaded command to get your webcam working which others have mentioned here:

[fixing your webcam in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126765/skype-video-not-working-after-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

There is also a guide on the page that someone has written so that you do not need to keep entering the command above.

Basically you need to preload this command in order to get your webcam to work. It does not work with all external webcams but give it a whirl.

Let us know if it works

Comment: yippeee can you mark it as solved please

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link to download](http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/talkvideo/hangouts/)  google hangout browser plugin

Use this [link to download skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/)

As the cheese is able to use the webcam , these software should do the same. :)