# Webcam not working in skype

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, webcam, skype, ati

Both of my webcams work in cheese on 11.10 & 12.04 ok. Skype recognizeses the cameras but will not show any output when I click on test video.

Yet my friend's machine which uses a Philips pcvc840k webcam works perfectly?  I use a Logitech c160 & a Philips spc200nc, neither works with Skype. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You'll find the solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126765/skype-video-not-working-after-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04

Answer (score 1):

Please first check if *video4linux* and *gstreamer* are both installed in your system! Also, provide any output of the *lsusb* program that include information about your usb connected webcams (for options see *man lsusb*).