# How do I get video to unfreeze in (X)ubuntu 12.04 with Skype?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, webcam, skype

I implemented that last post -

```
[Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype "$@"']
```

As specified in my `/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop` file, and as stated in the last comment: I also get my video working for a second and freezing until I move something near the camera, when it unfreezes.

Since my webcam works perfectly with Cheese and Video for Linux control panel is this not a library problem or is data compression set automatically which should be unset?

I have Xubuntu 12.04 on a 64 bit AMD computer with a Logitech Quickcam 2500 series. The video works fine in Xubuntu 11.10 and Windows (XP and 7).

Comment: The one at URL http://askubuntu.com/questions/126765/skype-video-not-working-after-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04,labelled "2" starting with:
First you will need to make sure you have libv4l-0 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Which Ubuntu are you using?

If you're using 12.04, you may install kernel 3.4.0 to solve the problem of skype video freezing. Hoping it is the same problem I had an not something else.

Go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/ and download the three files according to your architecture. Then you have to install them (using Software centre didn't work for me).

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T). Go to the folder where you downloaded the files by using "cd ~/Downloads" (change the path as necessary). Then type :
**sudo dpkg -i *.deb**

Reboot your machine and you should notice that the first grub line had changed to the new kernel (the installation updates Grub). If you have problems with it, you can always boot using one of the old kernels.

This was in an e-mail sent to me